# LibreOffice populating cells

Tags: spreadsheet, libreoffice

I have a spreadsheet containing data identifying the depot where a product is stored, the supplier of the product and the manufacturer of said product.

I wish to break this one spreadsheet into four .csv files and import csv files into an already created PostgreSQL db. Typically, depot.csv, product.csv, supplier.csv and manufacturer.csv.

depot.csv has <15 entries, supplier.csv & manufacturer.csv <350 entries each and product.csv < 2,000 entries.

Example of what I want to do.

I have created a list of unique depots in a worksheet called depot.

id  name

1. paris
2. berlin
3. london

original spreadsheet data

```
id  Depot   depot_id  PRODUCT NAME  product_id  SUPPLIED BY     Manufacturer

1   Paris     1    Hand wipes                    Erenco         Chem Group

6   London    3    Scrub Towels                Chemicraft   Chem Group

7   Berlin    2    WR2 Grease                    Greasy Bin     Chem Group
```

the column depot_id is populated by using the following formula

```
=IF(B2=depot.$B$2,depot.$A$2, IF(B2=depot.$B$3,depot.$A$3, IF(B2=depot.$B$4,depot.$A$4, 9999)))
```

and a worksheet called depot

Now I need a formula to populate product_id but above formula is not sufficient.

Thanks.

Tommy.

Comment: Thanks Nikita for the better presentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay it's working.

Formula looks like this... in cell C2 enter the following

=VLOOKUP(D2,Product.$A$2:$B4586,2,0)

explanation:

D2  = the text being searched for

Product.$A$2:$B$4586    = the search array, in another worksheet, being searched

2,  = the value to be posted in cell C2. This is from the column B in the search array. The leftmost column should be the column containing the value searched for.

0   = signifies a unsorted/unordered list.

See http://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?t=46746 for better explanation.
Also http://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_VLOOKUP_function

Thanks to Mauritz for reinforcing my research.

Tommy.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is probably best solved by using the **vlookup** function.

Comment: I have tried but I cannot fathom how to populate depot_id with id from worksheet depot using vlookup(). Is it possible that the third argument in vlookup() can do this?  Any tips?

Comment: Would it be possible to use a RegEx in this case?

Comment: Where do you get your product_id from? Do you have a 'products' spreadsheet? If yes, what are the columns in this spreadsheet?